# Find parent form control when it's in a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular10

In a child component I need to get a `FormControl` from a parent's `FormGroup`.  It's easy enough to do by injecting `FormGroupDirective` into the constructor and then calling `.control.get()` on that injected item.

However, if the form control is actually nested inside of a `FormArray`, then that doesn't work. What's the equivalent for getting the `FormControl` from the `FormArray`?

In my HTML I have just a pretty standard setup

```html
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ngb-accordion formArrayName="subspaces">
        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let subspace of subspaces; index as i" [formGroupName]=i">
            <my-custom-control controlName="someControlName"
```

By using the directive I don't have to actually pass in the `formGroup`. Ideally I wouldn't have to pass the `formArrayName` or `formGroupName` to `my-custom-control` but I can if I have to.

I'm wanting to avoid passing something like `this.formArray.at(index).get('someControlName')` to the child control.  I'm wanting to just pass the `controlName` and let the child "find" it directly.

I'm not sure how to get the `FormArray` instance from the `FormGroupDirective`

Comment: What do you mean by `then that doesn't work` in case of FormArray? What exactly did you try and what's the error?

Comment: The call to `this.formGroup.control.get(this.controlName)` just fails saying it can't find the named control. I don't know how to get the `FormArray` instance in the custom control from the form group directive.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: There is a typo : controlName="someControlName"  should be  formControlName="someControlName"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this code

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ngb-accordion formArrayName="subspaces">
        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let subspace of formGroup.get('subspaces')['controls']; let i =index" [formGroupName]=i">
            <my-custom-control controlName="someControlName"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're showing here. You just changed the syntax of the element being looped over. I already have a list of controls.

Comment: But as per your code it will not iterate on the formArray .`*ngFor="let subspace of subspaces;` this will search for a variable `subspaces`  in the  component.